# Solving the ODE with Odeint without using a np.linespace, but another array of time point

Tags: python, differential-equations

I would like my dynamic system to calculate and plot only a certain time spot. But as far as I learn, the setting for the time all using np.linespace, which is a continuous range.

How do I change my setting for the time in this case?

I would like to have those t which wanted to be plot out be the multiple of 2*pi:

t=n*pi,(n=0,1,2,3....)

how can I set up the time in this case?

Any array may also work? or only in the routines of np.linespace will work?

Thank you very much

Comment: `t=[n*pi for n in range(0, n_max)]`

Comment: For time sequences with given spacing use `np.arange`, like `np.arange(n_max+1)*pi` or `np.arange(0,t_max,pi)`.